# Eclipse 4.14 font size issue

Tags: eclipse, fonts, eclipse-plugin

We are using Eclipse 4.14 version for development purpose. Using laptop as well as an extended monitor, if I use laptop screen the font size and other menu size (Project explorer and other menu) looks fine with normal size.

**Shows a little big font and menu than normal**
[image: Bigfont]

**Shows a normal font and menu**

[image]

But if I move my eclipse to extended monitor, my text area font size as well as Project explorer menu size also gets increased. If someone faced such issues, can you provide some inputs related to this on how to resolve ? Thanks !

Comment: Eclipse 4.14 is 8 releases and couple of years behind. Please upgrade. Please make sure your software is up to date before asking. For UI issues, show a screenshot, tell which operating system you use and which Eclipse version.

Comment: Eclipse new version should be given by a separate team actually. I have attached the screenshots for reference. Using Windows 10.

Comment: The question still says _Eclipse 4.14_. Please upgrade and if you cannot reproduce it in the current Eclipse, delete your question; otherwise, update your question. Please make sure your software is up to date before asking to not to waste your time and the time of those who want to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Due to other dependencies we will not be able to upgrade it to the latest version of Eclipse. That's the reason why we still use 4.14